# Metadata Rejected, do I need to "Submit for Review" again?

Tags: ios, metadata, app-store-connect

I've just received this notification from Apple:

> Information Needed
>
> Your iTunes Connect settings indicate that your app serves third-party
>   advertisements. However, we were unable to locate ads in your app.
>
> Please reply to this message to provide the steps for locating
>   third-party ads in your app. When we hear back from you, we will
>   continue the review.

1. I dont know where I've made the error and where I have to correct it.
   -> I just use Apple iAd. No other advertisements provider is present.
2. After this correction, do I need to "Submit for Review" again?
   -> Im asking this, because I've red this page here: http://www.brynbodayle.com/an-easy-mistake-with-itunes-connect-metadata-rejections/ where it says I dont need to resubmit again.

But in the iTunes Connect Developer Guide there is something like this:

> If your app has been rejected because of a metadata issue, you can
>   resolve the metadata issues and resubmit the same build for review.

If someone could help me how to deal with this, I would appreciate it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your first message says that your app is using ads but the reviewer hasnt been able to found it on your app.

They tell you to just indicate where are the ads located.

All this is because Apple doesnt allow getting an AdvertisementID without showing ads (some people use it as unique-identifier).

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is strange for me, I just use Apple iAd and no third party ad provider. (like addaptr) And the ad is shown in bottom of every screen. Why they dont see them, I dont get it.

Comment: Its at the bottom of every screen?? ask the reviewer for a screenshot and provide a screenshot showing the ad in the app, maybe it was just a mistake.

Comment: Yes. Ive just done that what you told me (Ive attached a screenshot). Lets say what they will reply. I will update the post here.

Comment: how to  solve to metadata error but me try but not any email or message iTunes store side any other solution solve out this one bugs please let me know

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using just iAd from Apple, check the iAd code on your application. Probably you need to fix an issue on your iAd code.**Make sure the iAd is not set to 0 on Alpha.**  You can use the simulator to test iAds.
2. After the rejection, your will receive an email with a link to the Resolution Center. **(don't click on "Submit for Review" button).**

Send a message to your reviewer using the Resolution Center and wait a few hours. Your app will be "In Review" soon. Also you can "Submit an Appeal to the Apple Review Team".

Remember, If you make changes to your code, you will need to upload a new binary code. Probably you will lose your queue position and start the review process again (7-10 days).